# How to apply \raggedright to my table headings?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

Can somebody show me how to apply `\raggedright` to my table headings in this example?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{}
\label{}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X X X}
\toprule
Time of induction (\SI{}{\minute}) & Mean $\text{A}_{414}$ & Corrected $\text{A}_{414}$ (minus t=0 value) & Units of $\beta$-galactosidase per \SI{}{ml} of {\it E. coli} culture\\
\midrule
0   &   0.057   &   0       &   0   \\
1   &   0.060   &   0.003   &   \num{1.3e-7}\\
2   &   0.069   &   0.012   &   \num{5.0e-7}\\
3   &   0.083   &   0.026   &   \num{1.1e-6}\\
4   &   0.120   &   0.063   &   \num{2.6e-6}\\
5   &   0.123   &   0.066   &   \num{2.8e-6}\\
7   &   0.191   &   0.134   &   \num{5.6e-6}\\
10  &   0.310   &   0.253   &   \num{1.1e-5}\\
12  &   0.399   &   0.342   &   \num{1.4e-5}\\
15  &   0.491   &   0.434   &   \num{1.8e-5}\\
30  &   1.179   &   1.122   &   \num{4.7e-5}\\
45  &   1.585   &   1.528   &   \num{6.4e-5}\\
0c  &   0.056   &   0       &   \num{0}\\
15c     &   0.057   &   0.001   &   \num{0}\\
45c     &   0.055   &   0       &   \num{0}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You want only the headings to be ragged right?

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: Correct, thank you, I've edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\multicolumn` to override the original column specification:

```
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedright}X}{Time of induction (\SI{}{\minute})} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedright}X}{Mean $\text{A}_{414}$} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedright}X}{Corrected $\text{A}_{414}$ (minus t=0 value)} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedright}X}{Units of $\beta$-galactosidase per \SI{}{ml} of {\it E. coli} culture}\\
\midrule
```

`>{decl.}` inserts `decl.` directly in front of the entry of the column. Analogously, `<{decl.}` used after a column format declaration inserts `decl.` right after the entry of the column.

Comment: Beautiful!  That worked, thanks for the prompt response.  Can explain the use of the greater than `>` symbol?  And why did you have to introduce `\multicolumn`?

Comment: @ptrcao: I added some comment to my answer explaining `>{...}`. As I said in my answer, I used `\multicolumn` to easily override the original column format declaration.

Comment: Thanks, I see about the \multicolumn. Do you mean override in a hacky sense though? As in that's not really the intended use of `\multicolumn` but is a workaround to force an override of X?  Just wanted to know cause I've never seen `\multicolumn` used like that before.

Comment: @ptrao: [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) requires the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array), so it loads it by default. The notation @Gonzalo used can be seen by reading page 2 of the [`array` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf).

Comment: @ptrao: That is the intended use of `\multicolumn`.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for the link.  Regarding `\multicolumn`, I meant that I noticed it was being used in a redundant way, to specify a `\multicolumn` spanning only 1 column.  My understanding is that `\multicolumn` is normally used to span multiple columns.  So I thought Gonzalo was using it purely as a workaround to force some kind of override.  Does that makes any sense...?

Comment: @ptrcao: `\multicolumn` can be used to span multiple columns, but it can also be used to override the declared format for one column, as I did in my answer.

Comment: @ptrao: Yes, overriding a "single" column using a "multi"-column statement may seem redundant. But that's one of the features provided by the command by adding a "number of columns" parameter. Even if the number of columns is 1.